# CognitoCredentialsProvider on refresh throws runtimeException

Tags: android, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I am trying to upload a text file to Amazon s3 from my android application. I am using the following code snippet provided by Amazon AWS.

```
private static CognitoCredentialsProvider sCredProvider;

public static CognitoCredentialsProvider getCredProvider(Context context) {
    if(sCredProvider == null) {
        Log.i("Util","reached utility");
        Log.i("Util","Context"+context);
        sCredProvider = new CognitoCredentialsProvider(
                context,
                Constants.AWS_ACCOUNT_ID,
                Constants.COGNITO_POOL_ID,
                Constants.COGNITO_ROLE_UNAUTH,
                null);
        Log.i("Util","returning scredprovider"+sCredProvider);
        sCredProvider.refresh();
    }
    Log.i("Util","returning scredprovider"+sCredProvider);
    return sCredProvider;
}
```

When the code passes through sCredProvider.refresh(); it throws the follow error.

```
08-05 02:21:24.908: E/AndroidRuntime(25712): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 02:21:24.908: E/AndroidRuntime(25712): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to   create service network.NetworkService: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
08-05 02:21:24.908: E/AndroidRuntime(25712):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2667)
08-05 02:21:24.908: E/AndroidRuntime(25712):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:153)
08-05 02:21:24.908: E/AndroidRuntime(25712):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
08-05 02:21:24.908: E/AndroidRuntime(25712):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-05 02:21:24.908: E/AndroidRuntime(25712):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-05 02:21:24.908: E/AndroidRuntime(25712):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
08-05 02:21:24.908: E/AndroidRuntime(25712):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 02:21:24.908: E/AndroidRuntime(25712):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-05 02:21:24.908: E/AndroidRuntime(25712):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
08-05 02:21:24.908: E/AndroidRuntime(25712):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
08-05 02:21:24.908: E/AndroidRuntime(25712):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-05 02:21:24.908: E/AndroidRuntime(25712): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
08-05 02:21:24.908: E/AndroidRuntime(25712):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
08-05 02:21:24.908: E/AndroidRuntime(25712):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
08-05 02:21:24.908: E/AndroidRuntime(25712):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
08-05 02:21:24.908: E/AndroidRuntime(25712):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
08-05 02:21:24.908: E/AndroidRuntime(25712):    at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
08-05 02:21:24.908: E/AndroidRuntime(25712):    at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:278)
08-05 02:21:24.908: E/AndroidRuntime(25712):    at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:162)
08-05 02:21:24.908: E/AndroidRuntime(25712):    at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
08-05 02:21:24.908: E/AndroidRuntime(25712):    at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:645)
08-05 02:21:24.908: E/AndroidRuntime(25712):    at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:480)
08-05 02:21:24.908: E/AndroidRuntime(25712):    at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
08-05 02:21:24.908: E/AndroidRuntime(25712):    at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
08-05 02:21:24.908: E/AndroidRuntime(25712):    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(Unknown Source)
08-05 02:21:24.908: E/AndroidRuntime(25712):    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(Unknown Source)
08-05 02:21:24.908: E/AndroidRuntime(25712):    at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityServiceClient.invoke(Unknown Source)
08-05 02:21:24.908: E/AndroidRuntime(25712):    at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityServiceClient.getOpenIdToken(Unknown Source)
08-05 02:21:24.908: E/AndroidRuntime(25712):    at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.startSession(Unknown Source)
08-05 02:21:24.908: E/AndroidRuntime(25712):    at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.refresh(Unknown Source)
08-05 02:21:24.908: E/AndroidRuntime(25712):    at com.chan.censioevlog.Util.getCredProvider(Util.java:41)
08-05 02:21:24.908: E/AndroidRuntime(25712):    at network.NetworkService.onCreate(NetworkService.java:55)
08-05 02:21:24.908: E/AndroidRuntime(25712):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2657)
08-05 02:21:24.908: E/AndroidRuntime(25712):    ... 10 more
```

Commenting out the line run the application fine. But I don't see the file uploaded to Amazon S3. I did setup to Amazon Cognito credential provider.

The source code can be found [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/S3_TransferManager).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CognitoCredentialsProvider.refresh() will make a network request to fetch Cognito identity id and session credentials if those aren't cached (handled by the provider itself). Based on the stack trace, you call getCredProvider(Context context) on the main thread. And refresh() is invoked on the main thread. That's why you see [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html). To fix this issue, you can remove sCredProvider.refresh(). If for some reason you want to call refresh(), you need to call it in a background thread. Please refer to [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).